# Mutual exclusive operations in UI thread with Dispatcher.PushFrame and Application.DoEvents

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, dispatcher

**The situation**

I'll try to explain my Problem with a small example. I have a class that manages a view-stack. Replaces views shows and initializes them etc.

```
class ViewManager()
{
    void ReplaceView()
    {
        RemoveView(...);
        InitializeView(...); // this code may call Application.DoEvents()
        AddNewView(...);
    }

    void ShowModalView()
    {
        ShowView();
        Dispatcher.PushFrame()
        ....
        // wait until view can be removed
        RemoveView();
    }

   void RemoveView()
   {
     ...
   }
   // ... more functions
}
```

Because the ViewManager does a lot with UI elements, other Threads uses the ViewManager through Dispatcher.Invoke.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => m_viewManager.Remove(someView)));
```

If now multiple threads Invoke actions on the ViewManager, and one of them calls deep down somewhere in the code Application.DoEvents or DispatcherPushFrame, a second MessageLoop is spawned that will invoke another method o n the view Manager.

**The Problem:**

- ShowModalView is called and calls PushFrame.
- During ShowModalView another thread calls ShowModalView or ReplaceView.
- Because the new message loop executes all tasks queued to the dispatcher this method are also executed.
- Therefore two methods of the ViewManager are executed "at the same time" - or better because it is the same thread - nested in each other.

Locking inside the ViewManager is useless, because it is all the same thread. A semaphore might freeze the UI thread, because during the Message loop of the "ShowModalView" another thread can invoke ShowModalView on the dispatcher and that will freeze the UI thread.

**The Questions:**

- During the "ShowModalView" the UI thread should handle input / paint etc but should not handle other tasks invoked through "Dispatcher.Invoke" Is this possible?
- Do you have other Ideas to solve this problem?

Thank you for your hints and answers

Manuel

**EDIT:**
One solution might be to get rid of all DoEvents and PushFrame code. This is very hard to achieve but probably the only right solution. This post explains a part of my Problem

[Use of Application.DoEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents/5183623#5183623)

Comment: This is one of the main reasons why you shouldn't be using `DoEvents`, or their equivalent.  It makes programming everything else in your application a *lot* harder.  You should be using proper asynchrony, and offloading extended non-UI CPU bound work to a background thread, rather than using `DoEvents` or an equivalent.  Rather than digging yourself deeper and deeping into a hole trying to hack yourself out of a hack, *fix the broken code*.

Comment: Yes i totally agree. I do all my work in Non-UI threads. But i've not yet found a solution to properly display a own type of a modal dialog that only handles User input an nothing else. The hard part is to find an appropriate replacement for all the code that currently uses Application.DoEvents(). But i think that's the way to go.

Comment: Create a window and call `ShowDialog` on it.  Voila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Servy said, get rid of Application.DoEvents() and Dispatcher.PushFrame is the only clean solution. Sometimes this will cause a lot of refactoring but it is worth the effort.